# Scala: Compare types

Tags: scala

I want to define a function that could compare two class types. I have defined two different classes:

```
abstract class Task
case class DefinedTask(id: Long) extends Task
case class EmptyTask() extends Task
```

Then I have a function that returns an object of type `Task`, that could be either `DefinedTask` or `EmptyTask`.

Now, what I'd like to do is to have a function that identifies if this object is a `DefinedTask` or just an `EmptyTask`. The problem would be simple, I'd use pattern matching. But I want to generalize it because multiple classes go with this `Defined/Empty` pattern.

What I'd tried so far is:

```
def makeReturned[T: Manifest, U: Manifest](obj: T)(u: U)(f: T => Value) = 
   if(manifest[U] equals manifest[T]) f(obj) else
     throw new IllegalArgumentException()
}
//call to it
makeReturned(task)(DefinedTask)(makeTask)
```

`U` is always `DefinedTask`, `T` could be either `DefinedTask or EmptyTask`, but it is returned as `Task`.

```
manifest[U].erasure.toString //"class DefinedTask$"
manifest[T].erasure.toString //"class Task"
```

Which is right from the compiler's stand point but it's not for me. So, my question is how could I compare them in a way that would give me what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are some mistakes in your code:

   - You should make the `abstract class Task` sealed for exhaustive pattern matching
   - Empty case classes are deprecated. The compiler should have warned you about it. `case object EmptyTask extends Task` would be the correct alternative
2. Both case classes and case objects extend the trait [`Product`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Product.html). You can check the product on being empty with either of the following ways:

   - `task.productArity == 0`
   - `task.productIterator.isEmpty`
3. I think you'd be much better off reapproaching your problem. Why not just use the standard `Option` and have the instances of a simple `case class Task(id: Int)` wrapped in it? This could be the general approach for all the other similar entities of yours.

Comment: I already rewrote some code and instead of returning EmptyTask, it throws an Exception that I handle in the calling functions. Is this a good alternative?

Comment: The recommended way of doing Scala is a functional way, and in functional programming throwing exceptions as part of a normal program flow is a no-no. For solving that kind of problems functionally Scala provides the types `Option`, `Either` and `Try`. So from that perspective, no, this is not a good alternative. If, however, you write your program imperatively, you can just stick to the old Java conventions.

Comment: What I am working on, is actually a web app. How would I know the cause of failure then?

Comment: An unexisting task is not a failure. If you want to pass the information on why it's missing use `Either`, wrapping an existing task value in `Right` and the information on why it's missing in a `Left` for a missing task. I know, it can be hard to switch for imperative set of mind, to such concepts, but it's definitely worth it. Go ahead and google for info on using those types in Scala, you'll definitely find enough reading material

Comment: I want to switch from imperative to functional. Let's take another situation. The user requests something he has no privileges for. How would a functional flow handle that? With an Either that in the left would have a message that reports that?

Comment: and one more thing, in my framework there are a few functions that throw exceptions if for example, they're trying to parse some data that is not available. Would this also be a good case for `Either`? As for `Try`, when I try to import it `scala.util.Try` I get a `Try is not a member of Util` Exception. I am using Scala 2.9

Comment: Yes, you got the `Either` right. With regards to `Try`, AFAIK it comes with Scala 2.10 - the main purpose of this type is handling the exception-throwing APIs, such as the ones you're talking about, in a functional way.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want run-time, not compile-time checking.  So I think you mean

```
def makeReturned[U <: Task, T <: Task](obj: T)(u: U)(f: T => Value) = {
  if (obj.getClass.isInstance(u.getClass)) f(obj)
  else throw new IllegalArgumentException
}
```

or something like that.  Look at the methods on `java.lang.Class` and pick the one that does what you want.